# Error with Lombok's @Builder with generic typed field

Tags: java, generics, lombok

I am having issues creating a POJO using Lombok's `@Builder` annotation and have it map to the expected type at runtime.

Here's my code:

**OperationResult.java**

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
@Builder
public class OperationResult<D>
{
    private D data;
}
```

**OperationResultTest.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class OperationResultTest
{
    @Test
    public void testGenerics()
    {
        OperationResult<String> restult = OperationResult.builder()
            .data("Test")
            .build();
    }
}
```

This results in a compilation error stating the returned type is `OperationResult<Object>` and cannot be casted to the expected type of `OperationResult<String>`.

Is it possible to use generics and know the returned type using Lombok's `@Builder` annotation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To resolve the compilation error, you should define the generic when calling the `builder()` method like so:

```java
OperationResult<String> result = OperationResult.<String>builder()
    .data("Test")
    .build();
```