# Bad return type in lambda expression due to usage of generics in builder pattern

Tags: java, generics

I have coded the following builder (simplified version):

```
public static final class Builder<T extends SigEvents> {
    private Class<T> sigEventsType;
    private BiFunction<T, MessageExtractor, SigEventsEmitter<T>> emitterMapper;

    public Builder<T> forEmitter(@Nonnull Class<T> emitterType, @Nonnull BiFunction<T, MessageExtractor, SigEventsEmitter<T>> emitterMapper) {
        this.sigEventsType = emitterType;
        this.emitterMapper = emitterMapper;
        return this;
    }

    public SigEventsEmitter<T> buildEmitter() {
        //do some stuff which end up setting sigEventLogger and sink
        return emitterMapper.apply(sigEventLogger, sink);
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to use it to initialize an instance of `JSFSigEventsEmitter`, which is declared as such:

```
public final class JSFSigEventsEmitter extends SigEventsEmitter<JSFCoreSigEvents> {

    public JSFSigEventsEmitter(@Nonnull MessageExtractor messageExtractor, @Nonnull JSFCoreSigEvents emitter) {
        super(emitter, messageExtractor);
    }
}
```

... where:

- The class `SigEventsEmitter` is parametrized as such: `public class SigEventsEmitter<T extends SigEvents> {`
- The class `JSFCoreSigEvents` is `public interface JSFCoreSigEvents extends CoreSigEvents` which on its own is `public interface CoreSigEvents extends SigEvents`, that is the base interface of my builder

With the given context, when I try to use the builder as such:

```
    SigEventsEmitter<JSFCoreSigEvents> sigEventEmitter = SigEventFactory.newSigEventEmitterBuilder()
            .forEmitter(JSFCoreSigEvents.class, ((jsfCoreSigEvents, messageExtractor) -> new JSFSigEventsEmitter(messageExtractor, (JSFCoreSigEvents) jsfCoreSigEvents)))
            .buildEmitter();
```

... I get an error in the return of the lambda expression, specifically: `Bad return type in lambda expression: JSFSigEventsEmitter cannot be converted to SigEventsEmitter<SigEvents>`.

I understand that this is happening because of type erasure, but I don't understand why and especially how to fix the design.

The `T` in my `forEmitter` is a concrete type of `T extends SigEvents`, which I'm passing as `JSFCoreSigEvents.class`, and the return of the `BiFunction` should be `SigEventsEmitter<JSFCoreSigEvents>`, which is the case of my `JSFSigEventsEmitter`. Any idea?

P.s. the whole need is to be able to use this factory across modules which do not depend on each other, that is why I need to establish a common `SigEvents` and `SigEventsEmitter` contracts that can be used across modules and built through this builder.

Comment: Assuming `newSigEventEmitterBuilder` is a generic method, I don't think Java can infer the type parameters of that. Try specifying the generic type parameter for it explicitly. `SigEventFactory.<JSFCoreSigEvents>newSigEventEmitterBuilder` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks a lot, that was the right fix. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept/upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `newSigEventEmitterBuilder` is a generic method that returns a `Builder<T>`, the compiler error is caused by Java not being able to correctly infer what `T` is. You want `T` to be `JSFCoreSigEvents` as suggested by the type of the variable, but inference just produces its bound, `SigEvents`, as the result.

Java doesn't see that, because `newSigEventEmitterBuilder` is the first in a chain of calls. The language only considers the target type (e.g. the type of the variable you are assigning to) when inferring the type arguments for the last call in the chain.

A simple way to fix this is to just specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
SigEventFactory.<JSFCoreSigEvents>newSigEventEmitterBuilder()
    // and so on...
```

This happens a lot in other situations where you'd chain generic methods together, like with [Lombok's `@Builder`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73855512/5133585), [`Comparator.comparing`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24436871/5133585), etc.